# How to hold down the control key in watir webdriver

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, firewatir

Im stuck in my project today with a small issue , i need to hold the Control Key for a while and  select the {n} number of rows.

Below is my code snippet any help is really appreciated .

!!!...I want hold the control key click on a row ,then click on the other row and finally release the control key ...!!!

while (enclosure_count_remove > 0)

```
     $browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[0]").click(:control);
     $browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[1]").click(:control);
     enclosure_count_remove -= 1;
```

end

And the second way i tried is given below

while (enclosure_count_remove > 0)

```
     $browser.send_keys :control
     $browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[0]").click;
     $browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[1]").click;
     enclosure_count_remove -= 1;
```

end

Both are not working for me, every time im able to click but failed to hold and click both the entities .

Thanks!

Aditya

Comment: any particular reason to use xpath here?  I find it makes the code harder to read.. why not use something like `browser.table(:id => 'selectConfiguration').row[0].click`

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the watir-webdriver Element.click() method, I think you have to use the webdriver action builder directly. Try this:

```
action = $browser.driver.action
action.key_down(:control)
action.click $browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[0]").wd
action.click $browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[1]").wd
action.key_up(:control)
action.perform
```

I do not have a webpage to test this so am going purely based on documentation.

Comment: I  tried this Justin but its failing in finding elements so ... as i said i need to hold the control key and select the two rows and release the control key ...:)

Comment: When your original `$browser.element(:xpath,"//table[@id ='selectConfiguration']/tbody/tr[0]").click(:control);` does it locate and click the one row as expected? It seems a bit odd that it would not locate the element. Do you know of a page that has the same type of control you are trying to work with (it would make it easier for me to be able test different solutions)?

Comment: Justin im able to click on the elements but unable to hold the control key and select both the rows ..:(

Comment: Okay, I really do not understand why this solution does not work. Can you please provide an example page to test against?

Answer (score 0):

The click method takes modifier parameters.  That should allow you to do clicks with any number of keys 'held down'.  See [the rdocs on the click method](http://rdoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Element#click-instance_method) for details You should be able to do

```
browser.table(:id => 'selectConfiguration').row[0].click(:control)
```

Of course that presumes that you know for sure which rows you want to click and that they would never change.  Normally I'd be selecting the rows based on some matching some unique bit of text or other content, more similar to how a human might pick the rows to select.

```
browser.table(:id => 'selectConfiguration').row(:text => /text_fragment/).click(:control)
```

Comment: Based on the rdocs, I think the click method with modifiers presses the modifier keys, clicks the element and then release the modifier keys. I think Aditya is trying to hold control, click one row, click another row and only then release the control button.

Comment: Yup  exactly right ..Justin  i was looking a solution that you have noticed

Comment: It Should Not Matter.  After all a user might need to do something like scroll a list (or the screen) etc between selections.  The proper behavior the custom control should emulate is that clicking with control depressed adds or removes (if already selected) an option to/from a selected set.  If releasing control after one click, and then re-depressing it before another click does not work, you have a bug.  Test how a basic select list with multi-select enabled works in the browser.  try it manually here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple